# Why doesn't my networkstream contain any data?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, network-programming

I am trying to programm a ChattApp in c# using WPF and Multithreading but for some reason my Server dont get the Data.

MyClient

```
namespace Chat_App.Client_Server
{
    internal class Client
    {
        public void Communicate(TcpClient client, String message, System.Windows.Controls.Label messagebox)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("start Communication");
            int maxTextSize = client.ReceiveBufferSize;

            //send message from client to server
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            byte[] message_byte = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(message_byte, 0, message_byte.Length); // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                                                                // Console.WriteLine("Sent    : {0}", "true");
            messagebox.Content = messagebox.Content + "\n" + "message is sent";
            byte[] inputData = new Byte[maxTextSize];

        }

        public TcpClient createClient()//(String targetIP, int targetPort)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("start Create Client");
            //IsPortAvailable(1235);
            TcpClient client = null;
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
                // Verbindung erfolgreich
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Verbindungsfehler: " + ex.Message);
                // Hier kannst du die genaue Fehlermeldung ausgeben
            }

            System.Console.Write("Client loaded\n");
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

MyServer

```
namespace Chat_App.Client_Server
{
    internal class Server
    {
        public static TcpListener server;
        public static TcpClient client;
        public static IPAddress localAddr;
        public static int localPort;
        public static String data;

        public TcpListener createServer()
        {
            IsPortAvailable(1234);

            localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            localPort = 1234;
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, localPort);
            return server;
        }

    public void Communicate(TcpListener listener)
        {
            String data;
            listener.Start();
            Debug.WriteLine("start Connecting to Client");
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Debug.WriteLine("Connected to Client");
            if (client != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("client is valid");
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                while (true)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(stream.DataAvailable);
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            }
        }
```

MyServerWindow

```
namespace Chat_App
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public static TcpListener listener;
        public static TcpClient client;
        private System.Windows.Controls.Label label;

        public delegate void CommunicatorDelegate( TcpListener server, System.Windows.Controls.Label label);//TcpClient client,


        public Window1()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("start Window 1/ Server");
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server server = new Server();
            listener = server.createServer();

            Thread t = new Thread(() => server.Communicate(listener));
            t.Start();

            Debug.WriteLine("Content is rendered");
        }
        private void ServerBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Label;                                    //Get label.
        }
    }
```

MyClientWindow

```
namespace Chat_App
{
    public partial class Window_Client : Window
    {
        private String message;
        private TextBox textBox;
        private System.Windows.Controls.Label label;

        private static Client client;
        public TcpClient tcp_client;

        public delegate void CommunicatorDelegate(string msg);
        public Window_Client()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("start Window 2/Client");
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new Client();
            tcp_client = client.createClient();
        }

        private void Message_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox = sender as TextBox;
            message = textBox.Text.ToString();
        }
        private void MessageBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Label;                                    //Get label.
            label.Content = "";                                             //set Data from preveus conversations
        }

        private void Send_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label.Content = label.Content + "\n"+ message;
            textBox.Clear();
            client.Communicate(tcp_client, message, label);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that after sending Data over the Stream I woud get a true value from the Methode stream.DataAvailable. But it always is false. I already checked that my ports are open so the firewall is not the problem.

Comment: does it get as far as `Debug.WriteLine("client is valid");` ?

Comment: Perhaps `Message_TextChanged` is triggered when you run `textBox.Clear()`? If this happens then the triggered method sets message to an empty string. This may be what's causing `stream.DataAvailable` to show false.

Comment: @GenericUser: your guess was right. textBox.Clear() does trigger the message_textChanged Event. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

> NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

I cannot see that this stream is disposed or flushed anywhere. So there is a decent chance the message is just sitting unsent in a buffer.

If you want to get an actual usable system I would consider using a library/protocol that allows you to send *messages* rather than using raw tcp streams. If you insist on Tcp I would highly recommend reading [stephen clearys TCP/Ip FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). Especially the part about message framing.